# What's the meaning "I didn't but only"?

Tags: meaning

I read the sentence below:

> ... Which didn’t but only because I didn’t know what it was

I guess it means I had no feelings about it because ...
But I am not sure. Could you please tell me what the meaning of "I didn’t but only" is?

The fuller text is:

> Charles had designed my course
>   schedule. He’d signed me up for two music classes and a course on religion,
>   all of which he said would be easy for me. Then he’d enrolled me in two
>   more challenging courses—college algebra, which terrified me, and biology,
>   which **didn’t but only** because I didn’t know what it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**didn't but only** is not an expression: you have to consider it as three separate words.

**didn't** refers back to "terrified me", so you could straighten that out by saying

> biology didn't terrify me because I didn't know what it was

**only** makes it clear that there just one reason, and **but** indicates that it's not a very good reason. You could use these two words together in a sentence like

> I passed the exam, but only by two percent.

Answer (score 2):

The OP doesn't realize where the [antecedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antecedent_(grammar)) lies.

> Then he’d enrolled me in two more challenging courses—college algebra, which terrified me, and ***biology***, **which didn’t** but only because I didn’t know what it was.

The relative pronoun, *which*, refers back to something previously mentioned.

The antecedent of “which terrified me” is *algebra*
The antecedent of “which didn't (terrify me)” is *biology*

The speaker was not terrified of (studying) biology because at the time she didn't know what biology meant or what it would entail.

Answer (score 1):

One added comma might have made it all a little easier to grasp at first read...

> college algebra, which terrified me, and biology, which didn’t, but only because I didn’t know what it was.

It's referring to  being terrified of algebra, but not biology.
The writer doesn't know what biology is, so isn't in any way scared of it.

Comment: I think the sentence also might also be implying that the writer _may_ have been terrified of biology had they known more about it at the time.

Answer (score 1):

**I didn't but only** is a bit meaningless by itself.

The "complete sentence"

> college algebra, which terrified me, and biology, which didn’t but
>   only because I didn’t know what it was.

Let me add some more info

> college algebra, which **terrified** me, and biology, which didn’t (**terrify** me) but
>   only because I didn’t know what it was.

As you can see **didn't** applies to the precedent verb. The speaker **was terrified** by algebra but he/she **wasn't terrified** by **biology**. The speaker wasn't terrified because he/she didn't know what **biology** was.